# How to display the array after the looping scanf statement?

Tags: c, for-loop, printf, scanf

So, I'm new in learning array structure, and I'm made a program that asks the user to determine first their array size, after the user inputs the data, I want to display all the data entered, here's the code:

```
{
    int num, i;
    printf("How many data you want to input? :");
    scanf("%d", &num);
    
    int datacapacity[num];
    
    for(i=0; i<num; i++)
    {
        printf("Mark %d :", i+1);
        scanf("%d", &datacapacity[i]); 
    }
    printf("\nMark %d is %d", i+1, datacapacity[i]);
}
```

**input**

```
How many data you want to input? :4 // 4 entered from keyboard 

Mark 1 :23   // 23 entered from keyboard 
Mark 2 :23   // 23 entered from keyboard 
Mark 3 :23   // 23 entered from keyboard 
Mark 4 :12   // 12 entered from keyboard 
Mark 5 is 4
```

The problem I have is it just printing `Mark 5 is 4` How to print all the data the user entered?

Comment: you need another loop that is very similar to your first loop, but instead of doing scanf for each array element you do a printf for each array elment

Comment: You need another loop to print the values from the array.

Comment: On an unrelated note, please make it a habit to print *trailing* newlines. When `stdout` (where `printf` writes) is connected to a normal terminal, output is *line-buffered*. That means output is actually written to the terminal on newline. If you have a leading newline you will print the *previous* line, not the current.

Comment: Am I need to add a nested loop or just a new loop?

Comment: Obviously a new loop. 1st loop: you scanf N values. 2nd loop: you print N values. That's basic knowledge that is covered in your learning material.

Comment: regarding: `printf("\nMark %d is %d", i+1, datacapacity[i]);`  this is after the end of the first loop, so the value of `i` will be `num`   Remembering that the valid indexes for an array are 0...(number of elements in the array -1)  so the expression `datacapacity[i]` will access just beyond the end of the array (I.E. undefined behavior)  Suggest removing that statement `or` replacing it with the output loop

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main() {
  int num, i;

  printf("How many data you want to input? :");
  scanf("%d", &num);

  int datacapacity[num];

  for (i = 0; i < num; i++) {
    printf("Mark %d :", i + 1);
    scanf("%d", &datacapacity[i]);
  }

  for (i = 0; i < num; i++) {
    printf("\nMark %d is %d", i + 1, datacapacity[i]);
  }
}
```

Use the above code.
In the above line of the second for loop is used for printing the array elements it starts from index 0 .

Comment: harsh Kanodiya, better to explain the added code too.

Comment: Done  thnx for your comment